# How to handle deserialization of null and absent properties with Jackson?

Tags: java, jackson, json-deserialization

There is a record class in which one of the properties is an enum field.

The results of deserialization differ from what I'm looking for. Obviously, when the field is null or absent Jackson does not use the `@JsonCreator` method and just inserts null.

I would like to avoid that "special treatment" and deserialize nulls (and field absence as well) the same way as other values.

**Model classes**

```java
record MyRec(
  String first,
  Color second
){}

// ---

enum Color{
  RED, GREEN;

  @JsonCreator
  static Color fromName(String name){
    if (name == null || "red".equals(name)){
      return RED; 
    } else if ("green".equals(name)) {
      return GREEN;
    } else {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(name);
    }
  }
}
```

**Results of deserialization**

```
        JSON                             actual            intent
------------------------------------|-------------------|------------------|------
 '{"first": "hi", "second": "red"}'   MyRec("hi", RED)    MyRec("hi", RED) |  ok
 '{"first": "hi", "second": null}'    MyRec("hi", null)   MyRec("hi", RED) |  ?
 '{"first": "hi"}'                    MyRec("hi", null)   MyRec("hi", RED) |  ?
```

**How to force Jackson to use the `@JsonCreator` method for deserializing nulls and absent values?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define an overloaded constructor in your record delegating to the canonical constructor via call `this()`, and annotate it with [`@JsonCreator`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonCreator.html) (*otherwise, Jackson would use the canonical one*).

The attribute `second` can be received as a plain `String` and parsed using the method `fromName()` you've defined in the `enum`:

```
record MyRec(String first, Color second) {
    @JsonCreator
    public MyRec(@JsonProperty("first") String first,
                 @JsonProperty("second") String second) {

        this(first, Color.fromName(second));
    }
}
```

**Note:** no data-binding annotations required in your `enum`.

*Usage example:*

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
    List<String> jsonRecords = List.of(
        """
            {"first": "hi", "second": "red"}""",
        """
            {"first": "hi", "second": null}""",
        """
            {"first": "hi"}"""
    );
    
    ObjectMapper mapper1 = new JsonMapper();
    List<MyRec> records = new ArrayList<>();
    
    for (String json : jsonRecords) {
        MyRec myRec = mapper1.readValue(json, MyRec.class);
        records.add(myRec);
    }
    
    records.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

*Output:*

```
MyRec[first=hi, second=RED]
MyRec[first=hi, second=RED]
MyRec[first=hi, second=RED]
```

***Sidenote:** possibly you might want to use* `equalsIgnoreCase()` *instead of plain* `equals()`.*

Comment: Sad, but looks like it is the only way. Thank you.